# WebRequestContext.Localization in UnitTest

Tags: dxa, dxa2.2

The code has usage of 
`WebRequestContext.Localization.GetConfig("<module_name>.<key_name>")`
and it makes a problem during writing UnitTest.
It is not a possibility to include that as a parameter in the call of the method from many reasons.

Is there any way to mock that WebRequestContext.Localization?

I checked Sdl.Web.Tridion.Tests which comes with DXA 2.2 solution, but didn't find it.

Update:
Our implementation has in some of the method usages of WebRequestContext.Localization.GetConfig(".") and when we write our own Unit Test to test that Business Logic it fails since there is nothing for WebRequestContext.Localization.

Answer (score 1):

`Sdl.Web.Tridion.Tests` contains unit/integration tests for (guess what...) `Sdl.Web.Tridion`, which is the Tridion provider and model mapping layer in the DXA web app architecture.

There are no unit tests for the Views/Controllers; those are tested by SDL using a suite of system tests, which test the entire web app (incl. modules) through HTTP.

Comment: (guess what..) I know that. My purpose is not that. Our implementation has in some of the method usages of WebRequestContext.Localization.GetConfig("<module_name>.<key_name>") and when we write our own Unit Test to test that Business Logic it fails since there is nothing for WebRequestContext.Localization. So that's why I am asking if there is a way to support for unit test.

Comment: I would recommend not to use `WebRequestContext` directly in Business Logic. Would it be an option to parameterize the Business Logic so it accepts a Localization? That would allow you to provide a (test) Localization in your unit tests. See also `Sdl.Web.Tridion.Tests`.